# tail of a list in Elixir

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I'm just learning Elixir, and I understand that a list - like in i.e. LISP - contains of a head and a tail. For instance, the list `[1,2,3]` has head `1` and tail `[2,3]`.

So when I do a `tl ["b", 8]` in the interactive Elixir command line, I would expect `[8]` as answer. However, my *iex* produces in this case

```
iex(45)> tl ["b", 8]
~c"\b"
```

Why do I get this result, and what does it mean?

BTW, the same happens when I explicitly type `:erlang.tl ["b", 8]`.

Comment: What you see (`\b`) *is* the tail of the list. It's the Backspace character, which has the [ASCII value](https://www.ascii-code.com/) 8, and is represented as `\b`. Try out `tl ["b", 65, 83, 67, 73, 73]`, and you get the tail, a charlist represented as the letters `ASCII`.

Comment: @pmf : Understood, thanks a lot. I'm surprised that this concept is limited to ASCII (0..127) and wonder how UTF8 or UTF16 is handled, but I guess that I should focus on learning the Elexir basics first.